# Plotting a rectangle with colour representing a value in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot a number of rectangles, all of which have an associated value. I can plot points with values using `scatter(x,y,[],value);` but the `rectangle` function does not seem to have such functionality.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the rectangle color, although not quite as a direct analog to how you do with `scatter`. When using `rectangle`, you have two color options; the edge color and the face color. To set the edge color, use a 3-element vector representing the RGB values, such that each element is within the range [0, 1]. 
e.g.

```
%make some arbitrary rectangle (in this case, located at (0,0) with [width, height] of [10, 20])
rect_H = rectangle('Position', [0, 0, 10, 20]); 
%sets the edge to be green
set(rect_H, 'EdgeColor', [0, 1, 0])
```

The face color of the rectangle is its fill-color -- you can set that by using a color string (e.g. 'g' is green, 'r' is red, etc) or by using a 3-element vector in the same manner as the edge color property.

e.g. these 2 commands will have the same effect:

```
set(rect_H, 'FaceColor', 'r'); 
set(rect_H, 'FaceColor', [1, 0, 0]);
```

In your case, you would just need some mapping for your value (whatever form it may be in) to a 3-element RGB color vector. I'm not sure what your goal is for the coloring, but if all you're looking for it to have all the rectangle colors be different, you could use some mapping function along the lines of:

```
color_map = @(value) ([mod((rand*value), 1), mod((rand*value), 1), mod((rand*value), 1)])
```

then have

```
set(rect_H, 'FaceColor', color_map(value));
```

where `value` is assumed to be a scalar. Also, if you're looking to do everything on one line akin to `scatter` you can do that too:

```
rectangle('Position', [x, y, w, h], 'FaceColor', color_map(value));
```

UPDATE:
To have this work nicely with `colorbar`, you'd have to save each of your 3-element color vectors, and pass it to the matlab built-in function `colormap`. Then call `colorbar`. I have no idea what kind of color mapping you're using, so just for the sake of illustration:

```
figure;
hold on;

%have 20 rectangles
num_rects = 20;

%place your rectangles in random locations, within a [10 x 10] area, with
%each rectange being of size [1 x 1]
random_rectangles = [rand(num_rects, 2)*10, ones(num_rects,2)];

%assign a random color mapping to each of the 20 rectangles
rect_colors = rand(num_rects,3);

%plot each rectangle
for i=1:num_rects
    rectangle('Position', random_rectangles(i,:), 'FaceColor', rect_colors(i,:));
end

%set the colormap for your rectangle colors
colormap(rect_colors);
%adds the colorbar to your plot
colorbar
```

Hopefully that's what you were asking about...

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to use the legend that matlab uses for `scatter` - a block of colour gradient with values marked on it. Does you know what colour mapping that uses? My goal is to use colour to display the value I have associated with it. EDIT: Matlab refers to it as a `colorbar`.

Comment: @superbriggs You would have to save all of your color vectors (so you'd have an [n x 3] matrix), then pass that to colormap, then call colorbar (and have your plot held). I'll try updating my answer to give an example

Comment: In the end I used `colormap` which returns a matrix of 62 rgb values `colorbar` uses. I calculated the colour from that and then set the limits of the `colorbar` using `caxis([min max]);`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @superbriggs If your question is resolved, can you accept the answer? (Or post the solution you came up with and accept that?)